Inject initial command into an interactive command after 10 seconds in a terminal?
I'd like to inject an initial cmd into the an interactive process 10 seconds later, the ideal is
 (echo "initial cmd" && cat) | interactive cmd
 <<other cmds 
 <<initial cmd (10 seconds later put initial cmd here) 
 <<[result of initial cmd] 
 <<(keep interact, not exit)

I know the example <(echo "initial cmd" && cat) | interactive cmd> is useful, but it insert the initial cmds too quickly, which is not what I want.
I want to insert the initial cmd 10 seconds later, and keep the window interactive. I have no idea.

Inject a subshell that runs sleep and then executes the command in the background:
echo "(sleep 10; initial_cmd) &" | interactive_shell

Note that this won't be useful if the initial command is intended to affect the initial shell process itself (e.g. setting a variable, changing directory), because it's in a subshell.

The terminal exit and show:Unknown command: '(sleep 10; initial_cmd) && cat'. Type help for more information.

Then you're not piping to a real shell, since it's not parsing the input properly.

The initial_cmd is only valid inside the interactive process, this does not work for my case.

I don't understand. It's being sent to the standard input of the interactive shell.

Actually, the problem is that the interactive shell will exit after it executes the commands that you piped to it. You could include a command to start a subshell in the string you echo to it. echo "(sleep 10; initial_command)& interactive_shell" | interactive_shell

As I mentioned, the sleep 10 can not be executed inside the interative command. My case is the special interactive command, not the interactive shell.

The error you show implies that interactive_shell is treating each line as a program name, not a shell command line.
